# Как запретить использование REST-сервера всем, кроме моего приложения?

Tags: javascript, yii2, api, rest

В приложении на JS необходимо хранить некторые данные в БД. Для этого был написан простейший REST-сервер с использованием Yii2. Благо, там это делается до ужаса просто.

Но возник вопрос - что нужно сделать, какие технологии применить, чтобы сервер работал только с моим приложением? Т.е. чтобы ни кто не мог "со стороны" выполнить какую либо операцию.

Comment: Как вариант прикрутить Basic Authorization на api, когда js попытается сделать запрос к api, то вылезет окошко с просьбой ввести логин и пароль.

Comment: @Vampir, уж не знаю, не видел ни в одном аналогичном сервисе такого подхода.

Comment: Можно использовать логин через социальные сети/гугл. Можно сделать свою авторизацию и хранить логины и пароли там-же в бд. Зависит от нужд к скорости создания и простоте системы. В случае если приложение должно само подключаться к api допустим каждый день, то тут лучше подойдет токен.

Comment: @Vampir, у меня есть логин через социальные сети, но я не понимаю, как он может помочь. Работает он (сейчас) полностью на клиенте. Даже если реализовать его через сервер, с сервера на клиент все равно нужно будет передать id пользователя и  `access_token`, необходимый для работы с API соц. сети. Уже этого будет достаточно, чтобы выполнить любые действия используя REST-API сервера.

Comment: От кого вы хотите защититься? От легитимного пользователя приложения который почему-то захотел сходить в АПИ самостоятельно? От злого васи, который перехватывает сетевые запросы? Или от кого-то ещё?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я хочу защититься, например, от  вызова функции, которая добавляет оплаченый период использования сервиса. Или, например, от того, чтобы история платежей одного пользователя была доступна другому.

Comment: 1. Не должно быть такой функции в открытом виде. 2. Для этого придумали авторизацию.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а что понимать под "открытым видом"? Список методов, само собой, я публиковать ни где не буду. Но можно же просто просмотреть заголовки HTTP и понять, какой метод и с какими параметрами будет добавлять оплату.

Comment: На сервере должна быть какая-то проверка, что данному пользователю можно добавить место, например потому что сервер знает (из какого-то другого источника, не от самого пользователя), что место было оплачено.  Защита от злоупотреблений легитимного пользователя возможна только на уровне бизнес-логики приложения. Защита от перехвата чужих данных — https + авторизация.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы явно не в ту сторону воюете. Если вы делает оплату, то запрос должен поступать не от клиента, а от сервиса который обрабатывает платёж. И обычно там уже реализован алгоритм проверки пакета через сигнатуру, вычислить которую можно только зная секретный ключ.

На примере PayPal
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо через админ панель если всё в ручном режиме.

Что касается Yii2/REST и BasicAuth, это нормальная практика. Документацию можно почитать тут
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html